# How to select the first row that met condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following View in PostgreSQL:

```
idshipment idorder  quantity_order  date   quantity_in_shipment percent_sent
 50          1        1020         1.1.16    432                    42
 51          1        1020         17.1.16   299                    71
 51          1        1020         20.1.16   144                    85
 51          1        1020         45.1.16   145                    100
 52          2         1           3.1.17    5                      100
```

This View shows shipments per order.
For example:

idorder=1 was sent by 4 shipments:

quantity in first shipment is 432 which means 42% of order was sent

quantity in second shipment is 299 which  means 71% of order was sent

quantity in third shipment is 144 which  means 85% of order was sent

quantity in forth shipment is 145 which  means 100% of order was sent

I need a query which will show me the **first date** where each order was sent above 75%. meaning each order shows only one row.
For the above data I should see:

```
idorder date
1       20.1.16  (cause its 85% first time above 75%)
2       3.1.17   (cause its 100% first time above 75%)
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (t.idshipment) t.*
from t
where t.percent_sent >= 75
order by t.idshipment, t.percent_sent asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT iorder, MIN("date") AS "date"
  FROM your_view
  WHERE percent_sent >= 75
  GROUP BY iorder
```

Answer (score 0):

use `group by` to get only one record per `idorder` and `MIN()` to aggregate `date` by selecting the earliest date

I created a table call shipment that has data like you provided:
and execute this query

```
SELECT s.idorder, MIN(s.date) as date
FROM shipment s
WHERE percent_sent >= 75
GROUP BY s.idorder
```

result:

```
idorder     date
----------- ----------
1           2016-01-20
2           2017-03-01
```

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the tip. I updated the query.